# Trying to store user input into array and database at the same time

Tags: python, arrays, database, tkinter

I am trying to store a user input into an array and database at the same time however I am only able to store the user input into a database but not into an array.

Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk
import cont
import pymysql


class Venues:
    def __init__(self, num, seatCap):
        self._num = num
        self._seatCap = seatCap

    def get_num(self):
        return self._num

    def get_seatCap(self):
        return self._seatCap


class Create:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root

        bg = Label(self.root, text="This is an image (Images/bgimage.jpg)").place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        framecreate = Frame(self.root, bg="white")
        framecreate.place(x=450, y=100, height=500, width=700)

        venuecreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the venue").place(x=50,y=100)
        self._num = Entry(framecreate)
        self._num.place(x=50, y=130, width=250)
        capacitycreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the capacity of the venue").place(x=370,y=100)
        self._seatCap = Entry(framecreate)
        self._seatCap.place(x=370, y=130, width=250)
        timecreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the time").place(x=50,y=170)
        self.time = Entry(framecreate)
        self.time.place(x=50, y=200, width=250)
        lecturercreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the lecturer").place(x=370,y=170)
        self.lecturer = Entry(framecreate)
        self.lecturer.place(x=370, y=200, width=250)
        modulercreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the module").place(x=50,y=240)
        self.subject = Entry(framecreate)
        self.subject.place(x=50, y=270, width=250)
        departmentcreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the department").place(x=370,y=240)
        self.department = Entry(framecreate)
        self.department.place(x=370, y=270, width=250)
        addbutton = Button(framecreate, text="Add", command=self.adddetails)
        addbutton.place(x=50, y=350)
        nextbutton = Button(framecreate, text="Next", command=self.cont)
        nextbutton.place(x=50, y=400)

    def adddetails(self):
        try:
            con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="timetable")
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("insert into timetablelist (venue,venuepax,time,lecturer,module,department) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                        (self._num.get(),self._seatCap.get(),self.time.get(),self.lecturer.get(),self.subject.get(),self.department.get()))
            con.commit()
            con.close()
            messagebox.showinfo("Success","Details Added to Timetable",parent=self.root)
            #i have defined an array here for the venue and the venuepax that has been entered by the user
            self.venue = []
            for i in range(0, len(self.venue)):
                self.venue.append(Venues(self.venue[i], self.venue[i]))
            print(self.venue)
        except Exception as ex:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Error due to: {str(ex)}", parent=self.root)
```

As from the code, I am able to insert the user details into the database however when I print the array it just displays an empty array.

Comment: When you print... what array? If you're talking about `self.venue`, you're initializing it to empty, trying to iterate over it to add something to the same array. That makes no sense.

Comment: @AKX i am trying to add the user input into the array but I am finding trouble to do so

Comment: Fair. If you look at your code for the array, how does it make any sense to you? It doesn't refer to any of the user input.

Comment: @AKX can you suggest a method that I am able to add the user input into an array and into the database at the same time, please?

Comment: What would you do with the array? If it's supposed to show all of the timetable entries in the database, then there's no need to add user input into it directly; just read the data back in from the database.

Comment: @AKX the main objective here is that once i have stored the values into the database i will need those values into an array to create an algorithm to generate a timetable that is sorted for the users (in this case the lecturers)

Comment: Right. You don't need to add the user input directly into a list. Think about how you can query from your MySQL database into a list instead.

Comment: Do you want THE SAME data that you inserted into database, inside a array ?

Comment: @CoolCloud yes I would like the same data that I have inserted into the database in an array

Comment: Well keep in mind, that everytime function is run, the values get reset.

Comment: @CoolCloud im trying to find a way so that when I have these values in an array, i am able to make an algorithm that generates those values into a timetable. Can you please help as I've been stuck with this problem for two weeks

Comment: Ok i will add an answer soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229084/discussion-between-jagdeesh-sandhu-and-cool-cloud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation:

Your mistakes is that your list will be set to empty list each time the function is run, so since the list is empty, `len(list)` will be 0 and hence the loop will run 0 times(ineffective), and your list will remain to be empty.

#### Solution:

What you can do here is, start by moving your list inside `__init__`, so:

```
def __init__(self,root):
    # Rest of code...
    self.venue = []
    # Rest of code...
```

Now there are two ways to proceed, take the recently added values from database and append to list OR you could insert the same tuple of values into the list.

Here, I will just show you how to insert into database and then to a list, because other method requires `if` conditions and more.

```
def adddetails(self):
    try:
        con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="timetable")
        cur = con.cursor()

        values = (self._num.get(),self._seatCap.get(),self.time.get(),self.lecturer.get(),self.subject.get(),self.department.get())
        cur.execute("insert into timetablelist (venue,venuepax,time,lecturer,module,department) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",values)
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        messagebox.showinfo("Success","Details Added to Timetable",parent=self.root)
        
        self.avenue.append(values)
        # Rest of code...
```

So your list will be in the form of:

```
[(n1,n2,n3,...),(a1,a2,a3,...),..] # print(self.avenue)
```